# Concept of Primary and Foreign Keys in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I got a problem in Openerp. 
how I can create a specific key as a primary key and then refer it from another table. Suppose I have two tables in my DB (Table A and Table B) I want only a few fields from table A into Table B not all... how I can do this ? 
if I inherit Table A class , its all relevant fields will come in Table B that I don't want.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to better specify what data you want in table A, and what data you want in table B.  Or do you mean you only want to show a few of the fields from table A when you are looking at a record in table B?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to change primary key. It is always `id` and is created automaticly.

The simplest way to inherit only few fields is to create base model for mutual fields for table A and table B like in example:

```
class base(osv.osv):
    _name='base'
    _columns = dict_of_fields
base()

class A(osv.osv):
    _name='a'
    _inherit='base'
A()

class B(osv.osv):
    _name='b'
    _inherit='base'
B()
```

It seems to me there is a build-in mechanism in osv.osv for this but it isn't used anywhere in modules I know.

Comment: thanks for your reply..
so you mean, i shall make a new class and then inherit specific fields from both classes into my new class ? but that wont solve my problem. Isn't possible to fetch fields with one2many and many2one relationships ? i searched for days but couldn't get the concept of relationships in openERP

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. You can create object C with many2one field xxx related to A or B and than call xxx.field_from_base on browse record.

Comment: And here you can get simply example about relationships: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218737/how-do-the-relational-fields-work-internally

Comment: thanks that was a kool example .. My question is i made a classA which have 150 columns, now  i made another classB and i want to fetch data from that classA into my new classB.now if i inherit classA in classB all fields will automatically includes in ClassB and the new table will have upto 200 columns... can you give me a simple example of how to get some fields from classA not all of them. thanks

Comment: I gave you example. You have to create class base with fields you want in both classes and inherit it from both classes with new name. Look also on technical memento https://www.openerp.com/files/memento/older_versions/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_v0.6.1.pdf Inheritance mechanisms.

Comment: You should use `orm.Model` instead of the deprecated `osv.osv`, and calling the class after declaring it is no longer necessary.

Comment: @DanielReis: is the "no longer calling after declaring" a v7 change?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you "want only a few fields" from the parent class? What's the problem of having all of them available?

There are several inheritance types, see page 2 of the [memento](https://www.openerp.com/files/memento/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_latest.pdf).

Delegation inheritance makes parent class fields available, but they are *not actually copied*.
In the database, it just creates a foreign key for the parent class table.